# How to reset UITextView attributedText

Tags: uitextview, uicollectionview, default, reset, nsattributedstring

Anyone know if there is any way to reset `attributedText` property of `UITextView` to default value?

I have a `UICollectionView` with cells that contains a `UITextView` with `attributedText`. When I create a new cell, `UICollectionView` reuse the `UITextView` but with old `attributedText`.

Anyone can help me?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

set the UITextView value on viewDidLoad.

```Objective-C
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
  _textView.text = @"";
  _textView.attributedText = [[NSAttributedString alloc]initWithString:@""];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, to set attributedString to @"" did not work.(changed color remains)

Below trick worked.

```
_textView.attributedText = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"a"];
_textView.attributedText = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@""];
```

But after this, all attributes like font size, font color is gone.
I don't know how to restore the original state before assigning attrString.